# What happened to my invites in Stack Overflow Careers?

Tags: support, reputation, stack-overflow-jobs

When I joined, I got 5 invites to invite others in to Stack Overflow Careers. I used two (neither of them ever did use the invite, though). But now when I logged in, there is no "Invite" button anymore. I can't even see the invites I made earlier (in Messages or elsewhere). (My profile Completion Score is 87%. My Stack Overflow account has reputation 38, with four bronze badges.)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Stack Overflow Careers is replaced by Stack Overflow Jobs, a specific jobs site for Stack Overflow only.

I think Stack Overflow Jobs does not require invitations any more, so your previous invitations are not useful any more, and thus voided.

Comment: That's correct. Invitations are not required anymore in order to create a CV.

Comment: The invitation could still be useful as a formal way to attract some good newcomers to the community.

Comment: Art thou sure? http://jobs.stackoverflow.com redirects to http://careers.stackoverflow.com

Comment: Yes, I am. The new URL is http://stackoverflow.com/jobs @phresnel

Comment: Argh, but then, what's http://careers.stackoverflow.com. I am pretty sure I should read the FM, but that's confusing.

Comment: That is the old site @phresnel

Comment: Just compared some job listings. The backend seems the same, just the frontend changed. Phew.